# how to see the console log output in std out in mqtt nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

The following is my code, and I want to see the log in my stdout. My client is receiving message as publish and just echo back to server. I want to process that received message in python so that I want to store that value. How to able get the message value on stdout

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://127.0.0.1',{
username: process.env.TOKEN
});

client.on('connect', function () {
console.log('connected');
client.subscribe('v1/devices/me/rpc/request/+')
 });

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
console.log('request.topic: ' + topic);
console.log('request.body: ' + message.toString());
var requestId = topic.slice('v1/devices/me/rpc/request/'.length);
//client acts as an echo service
client.publish('v1/devices/me/rpc/response/' + requestId, message);

 });
```

Comment: Your question subject asks "how do I see the log in stdout" but the question asks about Python. I think you need to be clear about the one question you want answering here.

Comment: @martin peck my intention is to get the log then I can by pass to that into python

Comment: Rather than wrap a NodeJS app, why not just use the paho python MQTT library and keep it all in one process?

Comment: @hardlib what will be the equivalent of username: process.env. in python

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `process.stdout` which used for this purpose https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout

Comment: process.stdout('request.topic: ' + topic);                                                                                          process.stdout('request.body: ' + message.toString());                                           You mean like this , Then also I am not seen any output

Comment: I wrote like this but no response                                                           client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
process.stdout('topic: ' + topic);
process.stdout('body: ' + message.toString());
});